# Unknown width in panel

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML and CSS and I have a problem with the width of a particular object.

The site can be found here: https://rawgit.com/NBenitus/Diplomatie-Online/master/ordres.html

Basically, I want the panel with title "Raptor vs Chessmaster" to fill the width of the image and nothing else.

I have assigned "display: block" (also tried "display: inline-block") to the panel, its children and parent, without luck. Also, none of the children or the parent have a fixed width nor a margin or padding, which I have verified using Chrome's dev tools.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code you have there is just really nasty, has too much classes, id's etc.

I fiddled it for you. Maybe this can help.

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/3m89rhqh/

```
 <div id='panel'>
    <div id='title'>Raptor vs Chessmaster</div>
    <img id='image1' src='https://rawgit.com/NBenitus/Diplomatie-Online/master/images/Diplomatie_Partie.png'>
 </div>
```

css:

```
#panel {
  background:white; 
   width:300px;
  height:auto;
  padding-bottom:30px;

}

#image1 {
  width:300px;height:300px;
  }
#title {
  background:#FFC0CB;width:300px;}

body { 
  background:#ddd;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When doing this change, the heading becomes the width of the image, but the rest of the panel is unchanged. Applying the same style to the parent still leaves the unused width on the right.

Comment: Thanks again! I am using Bootstrap, most of the classes and ids are reused from existing components. Is there a way to not set the width of the image or panel in pixels, for responsiveness?

Comment: you can set them in percentages. or you can use the new viewport units. for example: width: 30vw; but be careful with that as only new browsers support that. generally just use pixels or percentages for dimensions.

Comment: Excellent, works as intented :).